# Is there a way to check if a file exists using a socket connection with PHP?

Tags: php, file, sockets

I am working in a PHP project that requires the use of sockets to talk to a server and send transactions but if a specific files exists in the server then the socket needs to wait until the file is deleted, is there a way to check for the existence of the file with the basic php socket functions ?

I have looked through all the documentation but haven't been able to find something that can help me

Comment: You'd need to implement such locking feature in the socket implementation on the server side.

Comment: Do you mean the PHP `file_exists()` function?

Comment: Do you want the client to detect the presence of a file on the server, or is the server checking its own file system for the presence of said file?

Comment: I am trying to detect the presence of a file in the server that indicates that the server is busy processing a transaction and therefore I need to wait until the server is done processing and it deletes the file

Answer (score 0):

Socket function with file check is not exists. Example for waiting a file:

```php
while(file_exists('.lockfile')) usleep(1000);
```